# Make Emacs prettify-symbols-mode work on non-whitespace separated words.

Tags: emacs, elisp

The new prettify-symbols-mode in Emacs works beautifully for translating:

```
lambda something -> λ something
```

I'd also like to make:

```
lambda.something -> λsomething
```

Sadly, prettify-symbols-mode only recognizes spaces as word/symbol separators by default.

Any ideas on how to use '.' as a token separator?

Comment: I use pretty-mode and this behavior is default, maybe just switch to that. what language are you using?

Comment: @JordonBiondo, that's a nice option, but `prettify-symbols-mode` has the benefit of being built into Emacs (since version 24.3, I think).

Comment: Yes. I'd like to keep prettify-symbols-mode since it ships with Emacs (now), and seems very stable. I've had issues with pretty-symbols-mode, though haven't tried pretty-mode. To answer Jordon's question, my intended use is to visually compress self.method in Python to something like ◎method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Lindydancer, I ended up doing this:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (push '("self" . ?◎) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (modify-syntax-entry ?. ".")))
```

which results in a reasonable compromise output of:

```
◎.method
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that does the actual substitution is `prettify-symbols--compose-symbol` in `prog-mode.el`. It excludes matches if the character before or after the word has the character type *word* or *symbol*. In many mode, for example `emacs-lisp-mode` the `.` character has symbol type.

You could either change the syntax code for `.` in the major mode, you could tell `font-lock` to use a different character code when highlighting (see the variable `font-lock-defaults` for details), or you could do ju-jutsu on the `prettify-symbols--compose-symbol` mode like modifying it using `defadvice` or simply replace it with your own.